# How to extract polygon attribute based on point location using QGIS expressions

Tags: qgis, geometry, expression

I'm using QGIS 3.34. I have a point layer that contains a single point showing a site location (called "Site Location"). I have a polygon layer covering the UK with 12km squares containing some attribute data I'm interested in (called "CDD"). I'm looking to set up a print layout with some labels that dynamically update and display the value of the polygon attribute "Value" based on the location of the site location point. How can I use an expression to acheive this? I've tried the following, but it says 'No feature was found on this layer to evaluate the expression.'

```
aggregate(
    'CDD',
    'first_value',
    "Value",
    filter:=intersects(
        $geometry,
        geometry(
            get_feature(
                'Site Location',
                'fid',
                1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: `'first_value'` is not a valid 2nd argument for `aggregate()` function, see: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_nearest#aggregate

Comment: a field name would be `"first_attribute"`

Comment: Thanks both. Solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using the following:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='CDD',
    aggregate:='max',
    expression:="Value",
    filter:=contains($geometry, geometry(get_feature('Site Location', 'fid', 1)))
)
```